# How to get transaction hash of a transaction with web3ja

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

am not able to get the transaction record of the transaction my code is below kindly help me

here is the script tag I used

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous></script>

<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(window.ethereum) {
            ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
        } else {
            console.error("Install Wallet");
        }
    });

    $('#deposit').click(function(){
        var amt = 0;
        amt = parseInt($('#deposit').val()*1000000000000000000);
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            from: "0x0f63128d7274B30C8e30f884DA6469FF3dF2f8d9",
            to: "0x14DC4828b521cF4692Df0CBd4397857Fa267a2B0", 
            value: amt
        }).then(function(err, tx) {
            if (err) { 
                console.log(err); 
            } else {
                console.log(tx);
                document.getElementById("txnStt").innerHTML = tx.status;
            }
        });
    });
    
    
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i wanted to get transaction status - true/false only but am not getting anything in this

Comment: am not even getting tx in console panel

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for the web3.js sendTransaction function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html?highlight=sendTransaction#eth-sendtransaction-return) specifies structuring the promise handler like so:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
    to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
.then(function(receipt){
    ...
});
```

Notice that there is only one parameter passed to it, not both `err` and `tx`. Let me know if that helps.

> note that you can use a variety of event based handlers off of the `sendTransaction` function that could help you debug as well. see: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/callbacks-promises-events.html#promievent

Comment: @AshwaniKashyap awesome! glad it helped. I would appreciate you marking my answer as "accepted" if you could.

Comment: Yes offcourse its "Accepted" and thanks for help.